# Using express handlebars with vue js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, vue.js

I am building an app using express handlebars for server-side templating. On the client side, I want to use vue.js. However, they both share the same double brace notation `{{ variable }}`. Right now, my vue.js variables are not showing because my handlebars template is overriding it. For example:

home.html:

```
<div id="app">
   {{message}} //this will not show up
</div>
```

home.js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    }
});
```

HOWEVER, if I define `message` in my server side controller:

```
res.render('../views/home', {
    message: 'message from handlebars'
});
```

the message will show up.

So in summary, is there a way i can use vue.js for client side templating while still using express-handlebars for server side templating?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change the Vue demlimiters to [something else](http://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters), e.g.:

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}']
```

Comment: This didn't work for me as written, I currently have to set delimiters on each new Vew I create: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523427/cant-use-vue-config-delimiters-can-only-set-delimiters-on-new-vue

Comment: My answer applied to Vue 1. In Vue 2, you indeed have to set delimiters per-component.

Answer (score 29):

This can be solved by escaping the first brace in your handlebars template.

```
<div id="app">
   \{{message}} //this will not be replaced by handlebars
</div>
```

Comment: It will not be handled by handlebars.... but also not by VueJs (which seems to be the question)

Answer (score 2):

You can "escape" the Vue delimiters in Handlebars by using a [raw block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#raw-blocks):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('vue-js', function(options) {
  return options.fn();
});
```

Usage in the Handlebars template:

```
{{{{vue-js}}}}
<div id="app">
  {{message}}
</div>
{{{{/vue-js}}}}
```

Comment: this is simple and smart, but what if I wanted to use handlebars inside the helper? and the helpers defined by 3 curly brackets