# Using Vue.js in Golang's HTML templates

Tags: html, go, vue.js

I want to use Vue.js with the Golang's HTML template engine but as both use `{{ ... }}` for syntax, they conflict with each other...

Does anyone has already did it somehow or have any suggestions on how to overlap this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change delimiters used by Vue. Look the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I had found the answer just few seconds ago here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36530534/3673491 (for reference).

Comment: Ref.: Vue.config.delimiters = ['${', '}']

Answer (score 15):

You can change the default delimiters for Go templates. Use:

```
func (t *Template) Delims(left, right string) *Template
```

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims

Comment: That's also a useful information, thanks. However I personally prefer changing Vue's delimiters rather than Go's.