# Use of Vue in combination with handlebars and Node/Express

Tags: express, vue.js, handlebars.js

I've developed a CMS. This is a Vue SPA. This connects to an Express/Node server that delivers api content in the form of JSON to it via requests. However now I need to build the main site. I've decided to do it in handlebars because I don't want this page to be a SPA, rather I want it to be a more traditional site with different pages etc. I've also bought a template to use for this main site. From my understanding, this template works with handlebars because it contains some javascript files like jquery that would be in conflict if i was to make it a vue app. Am I correct in this understanding? Or could I use vue to make a website thats not an spa and that also contains other javascript files. The reason I am asking this is because I need to develop some small component-like features for the main site that I would much rather code in Vue. Which brings me to my final question, is it possible to use Vue components within handlebars. Could I install/create components that I could load into it?

Any help with my understanding would be much appreciated because whilst I feel I understand vue in the context of an SPA that makes API requests for JSON. I don't really understand how I could use it for small bespoke components that I could place in other web-pages or whether I could use Vue for developing sites not in the form of an SPA. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is possible, check these resources:          
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-use-vue-js-mustache-tags-in-handlebars-templates              
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530301/using-express-handlebars-with-vue-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import the `vue-router` into a Vue project. This is what makes it a SPA.

Probably the easiest way in your setup would be to run Vue without a build process. Just import the `vue.min.js` with a `<script>` tag and you can define your components directly with `Vue.component()`. Then, you can run the Vue app with `new Vue({ el: "#app" });` and the component is getting built. You can also have multiple instances of Vue on the same page. So, here is an example:

```js
Vue.component('demo', {
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in data" :key="item">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>`,
  data () {
    return {
      data: [3, 5, 6, 8]
    };
  }
});

new Vue({ el: '#vue-integration' });
```

```css
#vue-integration {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9);
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div class="your-awesome-page">

  Your awesome page
  
  <div id="vue-integration">
    A vue demo.
    <demo></demo>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise it was the router making it an SPA.