# Vue pass parameter using handlebars

Tags: node.js, vue.js, handlebars.js

Hello i use nodejs with express and handlebars and vue 2.6
I want pass  {{audioannotationid}} to my vue component but i can't,
**what are i'm doing wrong?**
sorry for my english

This my edit.hbs

```
<div> Editar audio annnotations</div>
<div id="EditAudioannotations" idParametro="beowulfdgo" >    
 </div> 
{{audioannotationid}}
```

This my component

```
<template>
  <div id="EditAudioannotations"  >Hola {{who}} 

{{valor}}
  </div> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'EditAudioannotations',
   props:{idParametro:{
      type: String,
      default: '0',
    },},
  data() {
    return {
        who:"world",
        json: {},
        valor:"otro valor"
    };
  },
  methods: {

    },
    beforeMount() {
    },
  
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

This my index.js

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/audioannotations\/edit\//)){
    // window.Vue = Vue
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
    Vue.component("EditAudioannotations", EditAudioannotations);
    window.vm = new Vue({
      el: '#EditAudioannotations',
      render: h => h(EditAudioannotations)

    })
}
```

This muy result
[image]

Comment: this question was answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530301/using-express-handlebars-with-vue-js

Comment: But i want pass parameter to vue

Answer (score 0):

I resolved obtain id from url becase i don't use routex, in vue add this method

```
 created() {
    var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
        this.ruta=currentUrl  
        //console.log(currentUrl);
        var ultimoSlash = this.ruta.lastIndexOf("/"); 
        this.ruta=this.ruta.substring(ultimoSlash+1)
  },
```